# Task /progress bar JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, task

In my javaFx app I'm trying to attach my progress bar to a  task which is supposed to execute some methods from another class, I cannot seem to get the task to run through these methods when i click the button for this task.

This is my search page controller for two words inputted by user

```
FXML Controller class

public class WordComparePageController implements Initializable  {
@FXML
private TextField wordOneText;
@FXML
private TextField wordTwoText;
@FXML
private Button pairSearchButton;
@FXML
private TextField wordPairText;

WordNetMeasures wordNetMeasures = new WordNetMeasures();

private double distance;
private double linDistance;
private double leskDistance;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
DecimalFormat pf = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
@FXML
private ProgressBar progressBar;
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator progressIndicator;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {}
```

Binds progress bar too task

```
@FXML
private void onSearchButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws    InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

   progressBar.progressProperty().bind(taskPS.progressProperty());
       progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(taskPS.progressProperty());

    Thread th = new Thread(taskPS);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
            }

  Task<Void> taskPS = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       updateProgress(0, 1);

        distance = wordNetMeasures.searchForWord(wordOneText.getText(), wordTwoText.getText());
        linDistance = wordNetMeasures.linMethod(wordOneText.getText(), wordTwoText.getText());
        leskDistance =   wordNetMeasures.leskMethod(wordOneText.getText(), wordTwoText.getText());
       updateProgress(1, 40);
        ProjectProperties.getInstance().setPathResult(distance);

        System.out.println("Distance: = " + ProjectProperties.getInstance().getPathResult());

    ProjectProperties.getInstance().setWordText(wordOneText.getText() + "," + wordTwoText.getText());

        String wordNetDistance = String.valueOf(df.format(distance));
        ProjectProperties.getInstance().setPathWordNetText(wordNetDistance);
        ProjectProperties.getInstance().setLinWordNetText((String.valueOf(df.format(linDistance))));
        ProjectProperties.getInstance().setLinResult(linDistance);
        ProjectProperties.getInstance().setPathResult(distance);
        ProjectProperties.getInstance().setLeskResult(leskDistance);
            ProjectProperties.getInstance().setLeskWordNetText((String.valueOf(df.forma  t(leskDistance))));

        updateProgress(40, 70);



        Database databaseConnection = new Database();
        try {
            databaseConnection.getConnection();
             databaseConnection.addWordNetToDatabase(ProjectProperties.getInstance().getWordText(), distance, linDistance, leskDistance);
            updateProgress(100, 100);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WordComparePageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
};
```

}

Class with the wordnet measure methods for the task

```
public class WordNetMeasures {


private static ILexicalDatabase db = new NictWordNet();
private static RelatednessCalculator[] rcs = {
    new HirstStOnge(db), new LeacockChodorow(db), new Lesk(db), new WuPalmer(db),
    new Resnik(db), new JiangConrath(db), new Lin(db), new Path(db)
};

private static RelatednessCalculator pathMethod = new Path(db);
private static RelatednessCalculator linMethod = new Lin(db);
private static RelatednessCalculator leskMethod = new Resnik(db);
private static double distance;
private static double linDistance;
private static double leskDistance;



public static double searchForWord(String word1, String word2) {
    WS4JConfiguration.getInstance().setMFS(true);
    RelatednessCalculator rc = pathMethod;
    distance  = rc.calcRelatednessOfWords(word1, word2);

    return distance;
}


public static double linMethod(String word1, String word2) {
    WS4JConfiguration.getInstance().setMFS(true);
    RelatednessCalculator rc = linMethod;
    linDistance = rc.calcRelatednessOfWords(word1, word2);

    return linDistance;
}


public  static double leskMethod(String word1, String word2) {
    WS4JConfiguration.getInstance().setMFS(true);
    RelatednessCalculator rc = leskMethod;
    leskDistance = rc.calcRelatednessOfWords(word1, word2);

    return leskDistance;
}


/**
 * Gets the ontology path for the word passed in
 * @param word
 * @return
 * @throws JWNLException 
 */
public String[] getWordNetPath(String word) throws JWNLException {

    String[] wordResults = new String[500];
    RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
    String[] posOfWord = wordnet.getPos(word);
    int[] wordIds = wordnet.getSenseIds(word, posOfWord[0]);
    wordResults = wordnet.getHypernymTree(wordIds[0]);

    return wordResults;
}

/**
 * Gets the set of synsets for the word passed in
 * @param word
 * @return 
 */
public String[] getWordNetSynset(String word) {
    RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
    String[] posOfWord = wordnet.getPos(word);
    int[] wordIds = wordnet.getSenseIds(word, posOfWord[0]);
    String[] wordResults = wordnet.getSynset(wordIds[0]);

    return wordResults;
}
```

}

Comment: `taskPS`is not yet initialized, when you're calling methods on it. actually you should get a NPE.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: My mistake, I've overlooked the curly brackets before taskPS. I've edited my answer...

Comment: Cheers for taking the time to answer, however its the actions distance = wordNetMeasures.searchForWord(wordOneText.getText(), wordTwoText.getText()); and so on that wont execute.

Comment: Is it not running at all, or only once?

Comment: Its not running any of the actions, if i put a simple system.out.print("hello world") it executes that but wont execute  any of the statements i need it to execute?

Comment: when i click the search button the task bar is just sitting loading up and down like in a infinite loop doing nothing ,the task wont carry out any of the actions

Comment: Can you post the code which initializes and shows the progressBar? Are you sure there's no exception in your task?

Answer (score 4):

A `Task` is meant to be used only once. To reuse it, you have to reinstantiate it, or create a class which extends `Service`.

`Service` takes care of creating and managing the `Task` and has the benefit  of not having to reattach the binding for the progressProperty.

The `ProgressBar` has to be added to a `Scene` to be visible

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    private Stage progressStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Button btn = new Button("start task");

        TaskService service = new TaskService();
        service.setOnScheduled(e -> progressStage.show());
        service.setOnSucceeded(e -> progressStage.hide());

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());

        progressStage = new Stage();
        progressStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(progressBar), 300, 300));
        progressStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        btn.setOnAction(e -> service.restart());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class TaskService extends Service<Void> {

        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {

                    for (int p = 0; p < 100; p++) {
                        Thread.sleep(40);
                        updateProgress(p, 100);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            return task;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```