# Java equivalent of signal&slot from QT

Tags: java, qt, javafx

I'm writing a JavaFX application and I have problem with updating progress bar in main form, when some task executing. So, now, I passed reference to MainWindow, but I think, that is not the best solution.

In QT framework, there is a signal&slot system - so, in JavaFX there is similar system? For example, after load file, my utils class should emit signal to update connected progress bar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087848/task-progress-bar-javafx-application

Comment: https://o7planning.org/en/11137/javafx-progressbar-and-progressindicator-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Signal/slots is just a wrapper for events that happend asynch, assuming you have an object of ProgressBar then you just need to do

```
ProgressBar myPB = new ProgressBar(); 
myPB.setProgress(someNumber);
```